# Prove that for each positive integer $k$, there exist two powers of $7$ whose difference is divisible by $k$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility, pigeonhole-principle

This is a question involving the use of the generalized pigeonhole principle.
Basically, here are the things that I know (but unsure whether they're relevant to the problem):

1. Powers of $7$ are always odd. Hence, their differences are always even
2. Their differences are always divisible by $7$.

Here's what I attempted to do:

Let $a = 7^x$ and $b = 7^y$, so $x = \log_7 a$ and $y = \log_7 b$:

$x\log_7 = \log a$

$y\log_7 = \log b$

$(a-b) \% k = 0$

I really have no idea how to set this up so I can use the generalized pigeonhole principle for this proof. I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track to solving this problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k$ divides $7^x$ $-$ $7^y$ implies $7^x$ and $7^y$ leave the same remainder upon division by $k$. Assume to the contrary, that all powers of $7$ leave a different remainder upon division by $k$. Clearly, there are only $k$ possible remainders. Considering the numbers $7$, $7^2$, $7^3$ ,...., $7^{k+1}$, according to our assumption each of them leave a different remainder upon division by $k$. There are $k$ possible remainders (pidgeonholes) as mentioned earlier, but $k+1$ numbers(pidgeons), hence the pidgeon-hole principle forces a contradiction. Hence there are two $i$ , $j$ such that $7^i$, $7^j$ leave the same remainder upon division by $k$ and their difference is what we are looking for